# Efficient way of finding perfect squares

Tags: c, mathematics, time-limit-exceeded

I was trying to solve a problem which needed you to count the number of perfect squares in the given range:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isPerfectSquare(int x)
{
    float s = sqrt(x);
    if (fmod(s,1) ==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int testcases;
    unsigned int a,b;
    scanf("%d",&testcases);
    while(testcases--)
        {
        int counter =0;
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        unsigned int i;
        for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
            {
                int last_digit = i%10;
            if( (last_digit == 2) || (last_digit == 3) || (last_digit == 7) || (last_digit == 8) )
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (isPerfectSquare(i))
                    counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code fails for certain test cases due to a timeout. I found that perfect squares do not end with a 2 or 3 or 7 or 8 so I ignored such values. Yet, I'm unable to solve this problem within the required run time.

I have found similar questions here, but either they were not in C or they didn't have answers that were quite relevant to C.

Could you suggest a way that I can optimize this code so that it could run faster?

Comment: 1) the returned value from I/O functions (I.E. scanf) should be check to assure the input/ conversion operation was successful. 2) the format string for scanf() should contain a leading ' ' (space) so any left over white space in stdin is consumed/skipped over.

Comment: this line: 'scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);' is inputting to UNSIGNED variables.  %d is for signed int.  suggest 'scanf("%u %u",&a,&b);'

Comment: the code does not produce a forever loop;  So what is timing out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The code needs to run within a time limit, which this particular code couldn't and hence it causes a timeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily find the number of perfect squares up to (and including) a number by simply using `(int)sqrt(x)`

If you want the number of squares between two numbers, you should simply need to do this:

```
(int)sqrt(max) - (int)sqrt(min)
```

Though note if `min` is a perfect square, it is excluded/subtracted from the range. You can use a +/- 1 if you want to exclude the max number (if it's a perfect square), or include the min number (if it's a perfect square), from the range.

Comment: That was a really smart solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3575018 Glad I could help! :)
Let me know if you need any more specific information about including/excluding parts of the range if my last sentence doesn't explain it well enough.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the main problem pointed out by @JPMC's excellent review,
there are some coding style issues too that deserve mentioning and you should improve for the future.

---

> ```
>     if (fmod(s,1) ==0)
>         return 1;
>     else
>         return 0;
> ```

This is good to shorten using the ternary operator:

```
return fmod(s,1) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

And since the `==` operator returns 1 for true and 0 for false, this can be further simplified to:

```
return fmod(s, 1) == 0;
```

---

The placement of opening braces and the indentation is strange in some places, for example:

> ```
>     while(testcases--)
>         {
>         int counter =0;
>         // ...
>         for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
>             {
>                 int last_digit = i%10;
>             if( (last_digit == 2) || (last_digit == 3) || (last_digit == 7) || (last_digit == 8) )
>                 continue;
> ```

Since in other places you put the opening brace on the same line as the statement (also known as Egyptian style), you should follow that style consistently everywhere:

```
    while(testcases--) {
        int counter =0;
        // ...
        for(i=a;i<=b;i++) {
            int last_digit = i%10;
            if( (last_digit == 2) || (last_digit == 3) || (last_digit == 7) || (last_digit == 8) )
                continue;
```

---

I recommend to put spaces around operators, and after `;`, like this:

```
        for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
```

Also after commas in function parameter lists:

```
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

---

The parentheses around the equality tests are redundant here:

> ```
>             if( (last_digit == 2) || (last_digit == 3) || (last_digit == 7) || (last_digit == 8) )
> ```

You could write simpler as

```
            if (last_digit == 2 || last_digit == 3 || last_digit == 7 || last_digit == 8)
```

---

Finally, I recommend to use braces with even single-statement `if`s,
otherwise [embarrassing bugs might happen one day](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

Comment: I would like to point out those are great coding tips (spacing, boolean reduction, etc), though I would like to point out that you need to be careful where you use ternary operators. Skipping the if/else is great in the end, but that ternary bit beforehand is sometimes a grey area. Most people say it hinders readability for people. I personally like them and use them for quick statements like that, but have read a few S.E. answers that discourage it, as well as at my workplace. Not a huge deal, but mostly people worrying about the readability of code. So use ternary statements wisely!

Comment: @janos Thanks a lot :) Will try and follow them from now on.